# INSTAL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES - trying to test not my .apk file on robotium

Tags: testing, installation, apk, keystore, robotium

it's for robotium test-login system

First i've un-signed a signed application downloaded java program from http://www.troido.de/re-sign.jar double clicked on
it to open it and droped apk file on it - so i have .apk without META-¬INF folder.

Next i've tried to sign it following this instructions:
 Open a terminal window / Command prompt and enter (the jarsigner tool is located in the bin folder of your installed java sdk
jarsigner -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass
android APPNAME.apk androiddebugkey

I found keystore location by eclipse >>  window -> preferences -> Android -> Build

```
i've tried to install app with debug mode :

Microsoft Windows [Wersja 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. 

C:\Users\Marta\Desktop>jarsigner -keystore C:\Users\Marta\.android\debug.keystor
e -storepass android -keypass android Facebook_debug.apk androiddebugkey

C:\Users\Marta\Desktop>cd C:\Users\Marta\Desktop\Android_tests\sdk\platform-tools
C:\Users\Marta\Desktop\Android_tests\sdk\platform-tools>adb install C:\Users\Mar
ta\Desktop\Android_tests\sdk\platform-tools\Facebook_debug.apk
78 KB/s (16093644 bytes in 200.626s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Facebook_debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

Maybe You know why it's not working

?

I will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. it works for me

To manually re-sing APK follow the below steps:

1. Un-zip the APK file
2. Delete the META-¬INF folder
3. Re-zip the APK file
   It will zip file as "applicationName.apk.zip”, rename it to: "applicationName.apk"

In Dos prompt/Terminal write following commands

1. jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 –keystore C:\Users\Rcoutinho.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android applicationName.apk androiddebugkey
2. zipalign 4 applicationName.apk TempApplicationName.apk

Then rename TempApplicationName.apk to applicationName.apk if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I did ^^it - step by step but now it's still not working - new information:

> C:\Users\Marta\Desktop\Android_tests\sdk\platform-tools>adb install
>   C:\Users\Marta\Desktop\Android_tests\sdk\platform-tools\FacebookTest.apk file
>   C:\Users\Marta\Desktop\Android_tests\sdk\platform-tools\FacebookTest.apk'does not contain AndroidManifest.xml rm failed for /data/local/tmp/FacebookTest.apk, No such file or directory

maybe You know what i did wrong?

(fail by fail..ehh)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: unzip the apk file.
        When u do this you well b able to see the folder and also AndroidManifest.xml file

2: Delete the META-¬INF folder

3: Re-zip the entire remaining content (all folder and AndroidManifest.xml)

Note: re-zip the content inside the apk. Do not go back and re-zip the apk (parent folder)

Then follow the remaining steps

Comment: i did it step by step but: C:\Users\Marta\Desktop\Android_tests\sdk\platform-tools\FacebookTest.apk'does not contain AndroidManifest.xml rm failed for /data/local/tmp/FacebookTest.apk, No such file or directory <<<but the .apk file contains AndroidManifest.xml